# Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

Even though I imported FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts always I get No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. error

I tried so many ways,

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
....
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
...
```

**add-activity.page.html**

```
    <ion-content>
      <ion-card>
        <form [formGroup]="activityForm">  
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Enter Description</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.description" formControlName="desc"> 
      </ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Enter Amount</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.amount" formControlName="amount"> 
      </ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Select Date</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="date" [(ngModel)]="newActivity.date" formControlName="date"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
        </form>
        <ion-button (click)="addActivity()" expand="block" color="success">ADD ACTIVITY</ion-button>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

**add-activity.page.cs**

```
    import { ValidationErrors, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    export class AddActivityPage implements OnInit {

      activityForm: FormGroup

      ngOnInit() {

        this.activityForm = new FormGroup({
          desc : new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4),
            Validators.maxLength(50)
          ]),
          amount : new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(1)
          ]),
          date: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
          ])
        });
    
      }
    }
```

What may be the reason behind this?

Comment: Does your `AddActivityPage` component is in the `declarations` under app.module.ts  or local.module.ts? You may share your project structure in the question or provide a Minimal Reproducible Example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 1):

Does `AddActivityPage` belong to the module `AppModule`?

Otherwise, you need to add `ReactiveFormsModule` to the module where `AddActivityPage` is being declared.